# Why is the sorting of the category only displayed for the first request (TYPO3, tx-news)?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I try to display Categories in ASC order, therefore I changed the line

```
 <f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
```

into

```
    <f:for 
       each="{categories->v:iterator.sort(order: 'ASC', sortBy: 'item.title')}"
       as="category">
```

and added

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
```

to the file ~\Resources\Private\Templates\Category\List.html.

Everything works fine if the page is displayed for the first time. If I change to the second news page (Pagination), no categories are displayed?

If I switch page to

```
<f:for each="{categories}" as="category">
```

everthing works fine!

I'm using TYPO3 v 7.6.15, News system v 5.3.2 and VHS: Fluid ViewHelps v 4.0.0.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Steffen